# electron dialog box not preventing interaction with page

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

So this may be a simple fix, but I have been researching and have found no solution. I assumed electron did this by default. In my `Electron` app I am calling dialog boxes from the `renderer` process using the `remote` api. Everything works fine except that, my dialog's don't prevent the user from interacting with the rest of the `BrowserWindow`. My two functions are as follows

```
// function for saving a gantt project projects are serialized into a JSON file
// the JSON is then stringified for human readiblity then thru the dialog api is saved to
// users computer
const saveGantt = () => {
  let content = gantt.serialize();
  content = JSON.stringify(content, null, '\t');
  dialog.showSaveDialog(
    {
      defaultPath: `C:\\Users\\${process.env.USERNAME}\\Documents\\`,
      filters: [
        {
          name: 'json',
          extensions: ['json'],
        },
      ],
    },
    (filename) => {
      if (filename === undefined) {
        return;
      }
      fs.writeFile(filename, content, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          dialog.showErrorBox(
            'Save Failed',
            `An error occured saving the file ${err.message}`,
          );
          return;
        }
        dialog.showMessageBox({
          type: 'none',
          title: 'Ganttron',
          message: 'The chart was successfully saved',
          buttons: ['OK'],
        });
      });
    },
  );
};

// function that loads a gantt project uses the dialog api to open a JSON file from
// the users computer then it is parsed to return a JSON object that is then parsed by
// the gantt api
const loadGantt = () => {
  dialog.showMessageBox(
    {
      type: 'none',
      title: 'Ganttron',
      message: 'This will clear the gantt chart and load new data',
      buttons: ['Cancel', 'OK'],
    },
    (response) => {
      if (response === 1) {
        gantt.clearAll();
        dialog.showOpenDialog(
          {
            defaultPath: `C:\\Users\\${process.env.USERNAME}\\Documents`,
            filters: [
              {
                name: 'json',
                extensions: ['json'],
              },
            ],
          },
          (fileName) => {
            if (fileName === undefined) {
              return;
            }
            fs.readFile(fileName[0], 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
              quickSaveFileName = fileName[0].toString();
              if (err) {
                dialog.showErrorBox(
                  'Load Failed',
                  `Cannot read file ${err.message}`,
                );
              }
              const loadedData = JSON.parse(data);
              gantt.parse(loadedData);
            });
          },
        );
      }
    },
  );
};
```

I am passing callbacks with both my functions. I know if you don't pass callbacks it will block the process but not prevent user interacting outside the dialog box. Am I missing something simple, or does this have to be hacked into electron?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So for anybody that comes to the question. I figured it out.
I used the `remote` api function `getCurrentWindow()` that returns a `BrowserWindow` instance from the main thread. You can use this to then put it in the first argument when initializing the dialog box. As so

```
import electron, { remote } from 'electron';

const { dialog } = electron.remote;

const win = remote.getCurrentWindow();

// function for saving a gantt project projects are serialized into a JSON file
// the JSON is then stringified for human readiblity then thru the dialog api is saved to
// users computer
const saveGantt = () => {
  let content = gantt.serialize();
  content = JSON.stringify(content, null, '\t');
  dialog.showSaveDialog(
    win,      // added the browserwindow instance here as the first argument
    {
      defaultPath: `C:\\Users\\${process.env.USERNAME}\\Documents\\`,
      filters: [
        {
          name: 'json',
          extensions: ['json'],
        },
      ],
    },
    (filename) => {
      if (filename === undefined) {
        return;
      }
      fs.writeFile(filename, content, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          dialog.showErrorBox(
            win,
            'Save Failed',
            `An error occured saving the file ${err.message}`,
          );
          return;
        }
        dialog.showMessageBox(
          win,
          {
            type: 'none',
            title: 'Ganttron',
            message: 'The chart was successfully saved',
            buttons: ['OK'],
          },
        );
      });
    },
  );
};

// function that loads a gantt project uses the dialog api to open a JSON file from
// the users computer then it is parsed to return a JSON object that is then parsed by
// the gantt api
const loadGantt = () => {
  dialog.showMessageBox(
    win,         // added the browserwindow instance here as the first argument
    {
      type: 'info',
      title: 'Ganttron',
      message: 'This will clear the gantt chart and load new data',
      buttons: ['Cancel', 'OK'],
    },
    (response) => {
      if (response === 1) {
        gantt.clearAll();
        dialog.showOpenDialog(
          win,
          {
            defaultPath: `C:\\Users\\${process.env.USERNAME}\\Documents`,
            filters: [
              {
                name: 'json',
                extensions: ['json'],
              },
            ],
          },
          (fileName) => {
            if (fileName === undefined) {
              return;
            }
            fs.readFile(fileName[0], 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
              quickSaveFileName = fileName[0].toString();
              if (err) {
                dialog.showErrorBox(
                  win,
                  'Load Failed',
                  `Cannot read file ${err.message}`,
                );
              }
              const loadedData = JSON.parse(data);
              gantt.parse(loadedData);
            });
          },
        );
      }
    },
  );
};
```

It will prevent interaction with the current window until the dialog box is closed.

Comment: `fs` is new to me. which part did you change exactly? it wouldve been a lot easier had you only posted, im assuming, the small part that was changed or inserted lol

Comment: @BugWhisperer I added the `win` browserWindow instance as the first argument in each dialog box this prevents interaction with the page until the window is closed. Also, `fs` is the [node module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system) that provides an API for interacting with the file system in a manner closely modeled around standard POSIX functions.

Comment: ahhh now i see it. thanks. im new to node and even newer to `dialog` and `fs`. is there any way to prevent or appropriately deal with the [`ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE` error that is created when a user cancels a dialog box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58199111/cancelled-dialog-box-without-selecting-file-err-invalid-arg-type)